# nginx - send file which is being written to

Tags: nginx

What can i do if i need to send file which is not on current server and i don't want to waste the time of client for downloading on my server?

I can't use proxy_pass to file server because i need to save this file on the main server to prevent re-downloading again and again in case this file is very popular - it will cost a lot.

I'm using download.php and X-Accel-Redirect. I tried to set the real Content-Length of file - it did't help, nginx ignore content-length header from my php script, it gives actual size of downloading file.

I tried chunked_transfer_encoding on; + header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
didn't help - the same situation

So in other words,

Client requests file 'test.mp4' from 'server_1'
'server_1' downloads a file from 'server_2' using http streaming.
So i can stream from 'server_2' but i don't need. I need send this file to the client while it's downloading...

Comment: Why can't server 1 serve the file directly? Please give more detail about your architecture.

Comment: Because server_1 retrieve file from backup on Sia Network.